# Routing solver for circuit-switched networks

Tags: routes, logic, constraints, solver, sat

I am looking for a program/a library/an idea to determine simultaneous routes for a given switching fabric and a list of desired connections.

The routes have to be non-intersecting and simultaneous. This is a circuit-switched system where actual electrical signals will be transmitted through relays.

In this picture 1-4, 5-2 and 4-5 are routed through, but multi-terminated connections (e.g. 1-1,2,3) are possible, too.
[image: Switching fabric]

The topology of the fabric is given, about 200 nodes, but they are not in a simple crossbar configuration.

Also, there are additional constraints, as some switches can only be switched on or off together.

Finally, a soft constraint is to prefer routes through the least amount of switches, but if multiple inputs are connected to one output, the lines should merge as close to the output as possible.
(that doesn't work in the crossbar picture, but imagine inputs 4(green) and 5(green) are supposed to be both connected to output 3(blue).
4 and 5 could be merged close to the inputs and then routed together to output 3, but it is better to route them independently and merge as close as possible to 3.

```
4-------------|
5-------------|--3
```

is better than

```
4-|
5-|--------------3
```

I suspect that this is a very simple problem for a constraint solver, but I don't know how to get started (which solver? / how to translate problem description into model?).